# IIS ServicePoint ConnectionLimit always set to Int32.MaxValue

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a local web application running on IIS which contacts a service deployed on AWS.

While I was testing the throughput against the AWS service I realised that my local web application didn't respect the ConnectionLimit value set in the web.config through the following code:

```
<system.net>
  <connectionManagement>
    <add address="*" maxconnection="48" />
  </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

Instead the following code always return int.MaxValue

```
@(ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri("https://myawsservice/")).ConnectionLimit)
```

This seems to contradict what I have read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998583.aspx#scalenetchapt17_topic14

> Increasing maxconnection enables more calls to be executed concurrently to a remote Web service. This attribute does not affect local Web service calls. An increase in the number of concurrent calls causes an increase in the utilization of threads that are used to make the remote calls.

I would expect Int32.MaxValue to only be applicable to local web services. I don't consider my AWS service to be local.

Did I miss something? Did I misunderstood the definition of local web service?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Nico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

If the processModel autoConfig attribute is set to "true" inside your machine.config then you can't override the ConnectionLimit using the web.config

```
  <system.web>
    <processModel autoConfig="true" />
    ...
  </system.web>
```

Set it to "false" if you want to control the ConnectionLimit but in that case you'll probably want to review the other values set when autoConfig is on.